# Compute matrix of sums efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

Given 2 numpy (1D) arrays, I want to compute the 2D array containing all possible sums of elements of those two arrays. For example, like this:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([1, 2, 3])
w = np.array([4, 5, 6])

sum_matrix = np.zeros((3,3))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        sum_matrix[i,j] = v[i] + w[j]

print(sum_matrix)
```

This returns the correct answer

```
[[5. 6. 7.]
 [6. 7. 8.]
 [7. 8. 9.]]
```

but I want to avoid python loops (and certainly a double one). Is there some nice numpy functionality for this situation?

I can think of one solution that avoids all loops, but it feels kind of like a hack. I noticed that if `v` is a column matrix and `w` a row matrix, then the matrix product `v @ w` returns the matrix of all possible products. I can translate this to sums using `log` and `exp`:

```
v = v[np.newaxis].T  # Turn v into a column matrix
w = w[np.newaxis]    # Turn w into a row matrix

print(np.log(np.exp(v) @ np.exp(w)))
```

This prints the same as the above.

**Question:** Are there other, less hacky, numpy solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.add.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), which will be applying [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) on each value in `v` and `w`:

```
np.add.outer(v,w)

array([[5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```